# Humanoid vs Bipedaloid Word Diction

Tags: biology, aliens

I'm doing an extensive write-up project, and I'm stumped for how alien species similar to the human analogue morphology (Two Arms, Two Legs, and Plantigrade-Bipedal standing/maneuvering) should be called. I don't want to go for Humanoid, because that's to on the nose and too humancentric for the type of setting I'm developing.

I want something more neutral, so I went for the terminology "Bipedaloid", but I don't know how easily parse-able a person seeing that at face value would know I'm denoting to a rough morphology similar too a human.

Do you think such a terminology I thought up is good or feasible, or can there be a suggestion for anything else that can help?

Comment: It might be polite to call them by the name that they call themselves. Questions asking for suggestions are generally off-topic here, have a look at the brilliant [meta post](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3624/how-to-write-the-perfect-question) telling you all about how to write a good question, and where to find lots of extra info.

Comment: Hello! I would say describing them as similar to people or bipedal is best. It's generally best to not ask for opinion-oriented questions though.

Comment: There are a good number of bipedal creatures that aren't humanoid.  Birds, for instance.

Comment: The word humanoid is basically an adjective that sums up the idea of "hey, those weird things kinda look like one of my kind", and basically sums up how we compare ourselves to the world around us in many occasions (which is expected when you can't be certain if you're not alone in the universe and the smartest thing around). Honestly no matter the word you use, it'll be conveying the exact same idea, except "bipedaloid" pulls up a Plato move that inadvertently includes all birds, several theropods, some crocodilians and some pangolin species.

Comment: Hi Nagaraja. The reason this Q was closed is that this Stack focuses on the rules and systems of a world - but we must do so within the constraints Stack Exchange has created, and one of those is that a question must have the hope of an objective best answer (see [help/dont-ask]). It's why one of the close reasons is "too opinion-based." Consequently, anything asking about aesthetics or "window dressing" (anything that can be arbitrary and anything that can be considered the "choice or decision of a character or people") is off-topic. As a result, brainstorming questions don't work well here.

Comment: Maybe the question could be answered on the Writing site?